# base64 not working in Middleware of Laravel 5.4

Tags: json, laravel, api, base64, middleware

My middleware Code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $api_headers = getallheaders();
        $error_msg = '';
        $error = 0;
        if (isset($api_headers) && !empty($api_headers)) {
                    
            if (isset($api_headers ['device_id']) && !empty($api_headers['device_id'])) {
            
        } else {
            $error_msg = 'Please send device ID header.';
            $error = 1;
        }
        
        if (isset($api_headers['device_type']) && !empty($api_headers['device_type'])) {
            
        } else {
            $error_msg = 'Please send device type header.';
            $error = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $error_msg = 'Please send headers.';
        $error = 1;
    }
    
    if ($error == 1) {
        return base64_encode(response()->json(['error' => true, 'message' => $error_msg, 'code' => 0]));
    } else {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I want to convert the JSON to a encoded string and send it as a response. So i used base64_encode to converted it into a string. But it is not working in middleware. I do not know its reason I made a lot of efforts but did not understand what to do. I am also attaching a screenshot of the error. Please help if possible.

[image]

Comment: you must return a `Response` of some sort from the middleware ... the middleware that comes before this middleware expects a response to be passed back through the stack ... you can't return just a string  (Request comes in, Response goes out)

Comment: @lagbox thanks for your reply. What to do if I want a string in response from middleware. Because only single string is returning in the entire API controller as response. This error has occurred only in this middleware.

Comment: JSON is a string already ... not sure what the issue is, why can't you just return the json response you have created without base64 encoding it?

Comment: @lagbox Due to some security, it has to be sent in encrypted form. This is the reason to use base64 for JSON

Comment: base64 is not encryption ............

Comment: Yes, but it has to be sent like this. But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what status code you want to respond with, but try:

```
    $encoded = base64_encode(response()->json([
        'error' => true,
        'message' => $error_msg,
        'code' => 0
    ]));

    return response($encoded, ?response status code?)
               ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Kurt Friars. The solution you have given is working for me. thanks for this.